# Registry permission for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

During web application creating i got below popup message:

"Visual studio does not have permissions to read the template information from the registry. this is often caused by registry permission problem."

Any one have any solution?
Please help me. i wana to see Visual Studio new features.

Thanks

Comment: This is something I suspect that you would have opened the Visual studio instance installed in other user profile. But it was not installed in  your user account and you do not have rights to access those folder location. Please check your system admin who installed the VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

this might be quite late as an answer, but I excpierienced the same problem and I found the solution on a msdn page : here is the original solution message :

I came across this issue with Visual Studio 2010 and Windows 7.  I did not find this problems source as of yet but, I have found many Visual Studio users encountering it. I tried Michael's solution to this problem and it did more damage then anything else. It even went as far as to make Visual studio to boot into "Shell mode" and tell me the registration was not valid.
Using System Restore I rolled back the changes made by the subinacl tool and Michaels script (it probably was not meant for Windows 7, causing the errors in the first place) .
being a long time visual studio user and a pretty good trouble shooter, I knew the subinacl was the proper tool to correct the problem, but the script was incorrect for my perticular setup.  I adjusted the script as follows: (this is a batch script)

```
    cd /d "%programfiles% (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools"
    subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio* /setowner=domain\user
    subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio* /grant=everyone=f         
    /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f
    pause
```

I tried to include the "setowner" command with the grant commands (on the same line) but it would throw errors all the time.
This script fixed MY "Requested registry access is not allowed" with Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010.
if you want to try this script: Follow Michael's instructions, but use the script provided in this post and replace the "domain\user" with the proper credentials. You may also need to change the Path of Windows Resource Kits if you installed it in a diffrnet place or are not using a 64 bit OS.  Before using this script please backup your registry.

I hope that that helped!

*the original web page was : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c273b0e1-7f46-4065-afaf-4edf285d2531/vista-wpfapplication-requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed

Comment: I tried your way but it didn't work. I am not on a domain so I left it empty, I just added my user name. Do you have any other suggestions? I also run Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Well I fixed it using the script on the link you provided but changing the path in his script to yours since I am on Windows 7.

Comment: yeah - that's right using %programfiles% (x86) isn't always something that works on 64 bit pc's

Comment: By the way, after running the script something went wrong with explorer.exe and I was not able to open any folder or open a new explorer window. To fix that I opened a command prompt and used: `secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose`. This might help others if they encountered the same problem of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  Followed the post by user2698666 without success.  Stuck Process Monitor on it and found there were more registry entries causing a problem called WDExpress.  Thought I'd post my fix incase anyone else has same problem:

> subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio* /setowner=domain\user
>
> subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio* /grant=everyone=f /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f
>
> subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WDExpress* /setowner=domain\user
>
> subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WDExpress* /grant=everyone=f /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem with Visual Studio 13, where i wanted to add a webtest project for my newly created solution.
Tried the above trics to set ACL but it didn't work.

Finally used the Procmon.exe to locate what visual studio was doing (Include only process name devenv.exe) and look for result Access Denied. It will tell you what registry key is not accessible.

In my case it was the regkey HKCR.webtest (HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.webtest) that caused the problem. Taking ownership and assigning acces to this solved my problem.

I do not know how the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The above didnt work for me as I kept being denied in regedit even though i was admin.

I found this on another site:

```
psexec -i -d -s c:\windows\regedit.exe
```

psexec is available from Microsoft here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

This gave me full registry access. I tried to give admin owner to specific keys like above but VS 2012 express was still throwing that registry permission error. So I finally just added Administrator to the permission list of the entire HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ directory in regedit. Then gave admins full control.

This worked. I can now create a project without that infernal error!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with permissions in the context discussed. The issue is caused by an incorrect path to the template files in the registry due to sloppy installation program testing by Microsoft. The incorrect path throws an error when a user tries to start a new project and, true to Microsoft style, displays a generic and meaningless error message about permissions.

Here's the issue specifically. In some machines (assuming `C:` is the primary drive and `user1` is the user's login name and version 2013) the location of the template files is `C:\users\user1\my documents\visual studio 2013\projects`. Unfortunately, the installation path written by the installer in the registry is `C:\users\user1\documents\visual studio 2013\projects`. So, it's pointing to `\documents` while the correct location is `\my documents`. To be sure, look where your `visual studio 2013\projects` folder is located - either documents or my documents - and change the registry key to the correct location.

For my example the key is at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\NewProjectDialog\MRUSettingsLocalProjectLocationEntries` the path is located in the `Value0` entry. Check it and change to make it point to exactly where your project folder is.

Answer (score 0):

Lars Meldgard's use of ProcMon was a good tip and helped me. I just wanted to include a picture of what an access denied looks like in ProcMon. I had to do it one registry key at a time--this wasn't the only one. It was very cumbersome and slow, but I was able to knock them off one by one and give full rights on each one. (That part is a hassle too, because I had to take ownership, then close regedit, then go back in so I could set the permissions; you can't do it all in one fell swoop.)

[image]