# Disable Admin Permissions Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

So,

I have somehow made it so Visual Studio 2012 is starting with elevated permissions (UAC dialog / Admin mode).

I **did not** do this by modifying my shortcut. Let me repeat, did not.

I believe my registry has been modified to do this. I think I installed a plugin sometime ago that did this, but need to change it back, and do not remember if that is 100% correct.

My Question: Does anyone know were this might be controlled in the registry (Win 8 64-bit)? Or if there is something else I am missing?

I have installed a lot of different plugins like I said, but the one that I can think controls this type of behavior is **VSCommand2012**. I have made sure that I have the option to force starting in admin mode turned off for this plugin.

I looked here:
[Registry permission for Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000194/registry-permission-for-visual-studio-2012), but the only answer is for Win 7 and VS 2010.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up removing the **VSCommand2012** plugin, and then re-installing it.

I then set the option to force starting in admin mode turned off for the plugin and it started working. That is, VS no longer start with elevated permissions.