# Visual Studio 2017 won't create C# and Visual Basic project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, permissions

I've just installed a clean Visual Studio 2017, and I've been working on C++ since, no problem on C++.

But today I realised that I can't open any other project in c# and VB.NET form app. It gives this error:

> Visual Studio does not have permissions to read the template information from the system registry. This is often caused by registry permission problems.

I searched for the problem but none. And I know this is not a permission problem. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: here is a error picture https://ibb.co/hpoiyK

Comment: Checked these steps? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/27650/visual-studio-does-not-have-permissions-to-read-th.html

Comment: Looks like certain Anti-Virus can cause this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/68bc9afe-3bdd-45ef-b84d-fd291f2c6736/problem-to-make-new-project-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-rtm-this-is-often-caused-by-registry?forum=vssetup

Comment: There's also a SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000194/registry-permission-for-visual-studio-2012

Comment: tried all of them. doesn't solve. also i dont have any anti-virüs or firewall. Same professional users think that this is not a register issue...

Comment: All Right i find the solution like this if you someone else have this error...
First download this windows tool and run it...
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510
Then create a restore point and download and run this program
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Security-Restore.shtml
restart the visual studio. it works. Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. First download this Windows tool and run it: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510. Then create a restore point and download and run this program: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Security-Restore.shtml, and then restart Visual Studio. It works now.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23510.
the link does not work